# Whether a csv file present in a particular directory or not

Tags: java, file

I want to figure it out whether a csv file present in a particular directory or not

Answer (score 2):

Something along the lines of

```
public boolean containsCSVFiles( File aDirectory ){
  return !aDirectory.listFiles( new FilenameFilter(){
     public boolean accept(File dir, String name){
       return name.endsWith( ".csv" );
     }
  }).isEmpty();
}
```

should do it (not tested in my IDE, so I hope I did not make to much typos).

Answer (score 1):

Simply parse the directory to look for .csv files....

```
File f = new File("D:/Shashank/");
        if(f.isDirectory())
        {
            File[] file= f.listFiles();
            for(File f1 :file)
            {
                if(f1.getName().endsWith(".csv"))
                {
                    System.out.println("File Found"+f1.getName());
                }
            }
        }
```

You can make it recursive too, to look into the sub directories.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really explain what you want to do, but between the `listFiles()` and `exists()` methods of the [java.io.File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) class, you should be able to get it done.